# Fuse will not stay in slot

Tags: ford, fuse, expedition

I have a 2001 Ford expedition the Eddie Bauer edition four wheel drive the fuse for my power brakes is really loose and won't stay in the slot

I've been having brake problems and I was it was suggested to me to check my fuses I checked my fuses and the one for my power brakes I think is what it was how it was worded it will not stay in the spot I seen on one of the other questions on here something about twisting 10 to 15 degrees? What do you mean by that I have no clue

Comment: Welcome Kimberly!  Please edit to improve readability.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a link to the other question you have mentioned?

Comment: My understanding is that power brakes work by a vacuum, usually created by the engine in gasoline vehicles. Is that vehicle perhaps a diesel, with a vacuum pump behind the fuse?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure I wrote the answer you're talking about ...

What I meant by *twisting it 10-15°* is, if the prongs of the fuse are pointing right at you, with the colored plastic of the fuse pointing away from you, twist the prongs so they are bent out of shape by about 10-15°. Here's an image of what I'm suggesting so you'll know:

[image]

If you look at the prongs, you'll see how I've twisted them. The metal used on these is fairly pliable. I'm not sure I've gotten the twist to 10°, but hopefully you get the idea. Twist them a little and if it still isn't holding the fuse, twist it a little bit more. If you are gentle and easy, you should be able to get it to a point where the slot will once again hold the fuse.